# React Nav bar Adjustment

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am new to react, so trying to create a simple navbar. I feel its very different from simple HTML and CSS. I have wrote code in Simple HTML and CSS and it worked but in react it don't.
well first issue is I want to adjust my `<Ul>` items to bottom of navigation bar.
second issue is when I add `contact us or about us` it breaks line and go to other line. this is my image and code please help.....
my code is :

```
code UPDATED changed UL 

.wrapper header nav ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: right;
}
```

now contact us and about us are in one line. still issue how to do vertical alignment.

html

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Navbar extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        <div className="brandName">
          <h1>PACHEX</h1>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">Picture</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">Video</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

CSS :

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper header nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #b5d404;
  padding: 0.5%;
}
.wrapper header nav .brandName {
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5%;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.wrapper header nav .brandName:hover {
  color: #ffff33;
}
.wrapper header nav ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}
.wrapper header nav ul li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.wrapper header nav ul li a {
  padding: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1;
}
.wrapper header nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffff33;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do not use float on your `ul` element. And if you don't want line breaks in your nav items, I suggest using `white-space: nowrap;` to nav-item

Comment: ok then it will not move on right side

Comment: just use style `display:flex` on `nav` element with `justify-content:space-between`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue here. firstly where when I add contact us or about us it breaks line and go to other line, it was Solved by
I have added `white-space: nowrap;` and then float right.

```
.wrapper header nav ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: right;
}
```

second issue was how to do vertical arrangement I have added `margin-top`

```
.wrapper header nav ul {
  margin-top: 1%;
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: right;
}
```

now it looks like this

[image]